# Why is my flair not updated with my actual reputation score?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, flair

I use my Flair image on another site, and I noticed that my reputation score there is not updated.

Since a picture is better than 1000 words:

[image: My actual reputation on Stack Overflow is 316, but my flair shows 261.]

Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: Eh looking at this now brings back old memories!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Flair is updated every 24-36 hours. Just wait.

Comment: @Jeff Shouldn't you put that information right next to the "(please note that only sites where you have more than 200 reputation will appear.)" sentence on the flair page?

Comment: @lars sure good idea, adding that now!

Comment: I just noticed the flair [HTTP headers](http://web-sniffer.net/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackexchange.com%2Fusers%2Fflair%2F49686.png&submit=Submit&http=1.1&gzip=yes&type=GET&uak=0) *also* state a flair image is good for two months: `Expires: Thu, 08 Mar 2012 12:10:36 GMT`, next to `max-age=8640` (which indeed is one day). Should I report that?

Comment: @arjan sure go for it

Comment: It would be better to note "flairs refresh every 24-36 hours" at the bottom of flair images.

Comment: @Youngjae this page already says "that flair is only updated once every 24-36 hours" right on it, and has for years...

Answer (score 4):

It also seems that the rate of refresh depends on the theme of the flair, i.e. the state of flair differs between themes as demonstrated in the screen shot:

[image: Demonstration of inconsistent flairs by them]

Comment: yes, that is true, it depends on the *last request* for that flair. Some of the weirder color themes are not requested too much.. *helllllo hot dog stand*

Comment: Good catch! :-)

Comment: @JeffAtwood but then why are the less used ones ... hot dog stand ... more up to date than the default one?

Comment: @Rory - probably because they are requested less.