# What's the rubric for flair updates?

Tags: flair, discussion, combined-flair

Why does the combined participation flair not update at the same time that Stack Overflow specific flair does? I imagine because the combined would have to perhaps query multiple databases.

Does combined flair update more frequently the less Stack Exchange site you belong to, or is this like a X times a day thing? If so, what are the update frequencies for respective flair types?  Or is not a pull, but a push; a change of score triggers it in some manner perhaps?

I have seen [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69401/flair-not-updated) btw. I'm looking for more detail though. Also, not complaining, just curious how the system works.

Comment: I have also found that while StackOverflow flair works perfectly (and is very timely), the network flair seems to take weeks.