# Combined Flair of Stack Exchange doesn't get updated instantely

Tags: feature-request, status-bydesign, flair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flair not updated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69401/flair-not-updated)

Combined Flair is best thing to put on website, but it isn't updated in real-time. If not updated in real-time, 5-10 minutes would be OK. But, I notice that it is intact for many hours. Please, fix it.

Comment: The current refresh rate is [meta-tag:status-bydesign] and this is not, therefore, a [meta-tag:bug] but a [meta-tag:feature-request]

Comment: @ChrisF: Hmmm, good point. Shall I leave it to a dev to decide/decline it then?

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn - It's certainly not a bug. Up to you whether you remove the status tag though.

Comment: @Bolt well, Jeff himself changed my own "bug report" [to `status-bydesign`](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/69401/revisions) so guess it's best to leave it be. :)

Comment: I have requested a similar feature: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122082/update-combined-flair-of-stack-exchange-on-demand

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[This is intended](https://stackoverflow.com/users/flair):

> flair is only updated once every 24-36 hours

And I doubt it'll be changed anytime soon. I'm not a developer at Stack Exchange, but it will be quite a load of work for the servers to recalculate **everybody's** flair across **every Stack Exchange site** once every 5 to 10 minutes. All for no real, conceivable benefit that I can think of.