# Bug in Flair of Stack Overflow

Tags: support, bug, flair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Flair not updated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69401/flair-not-updated)

See attached image of my flair on Stack Overflow.

[image]

You can see the problem: The flair shows a different a reputation value than the site.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Wait for the cache to catch up?

Comment: how much time it takes generally ? And flair under "CLEAN" theme shows something older than other themes

Comment: Don't know. Hours? Usually not more than a day. Though I do notice that one of the flairs has a *different* value to the rest which may be just timing, but could be something else...

Comment: thnks chris for adding image over here :)

Comment: 24-36 hours, [according to Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69401/flair-not-updated/69403#69403), @ChrisF. Also note that this counts since the flair was generated: if one theme is requested earlier than another, then [themes can be out of sync too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69401/flair-not-updated#comment317415_120182).

Comment: I really think that this discussion should be opened again, since there seems to be some problems as you can see in my comment to Kevin's answer.

Comment: And this is not a duplicate to the other post. The bug is not in the update process, it is elsewhere, very probably in your data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Caching, caching, caching.   The answer is always caching.

Comment: It is not always caching! Please, see my Flair now, showing 275 points total, although it should be something like 11k. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/62073194/Screen%20Shot%202012-06-16%20at%201.25.42%20AM.png Your system seems to have internal problems with search and data structures.

Comment: That's your Area 51 flair, where you *do* have exactly 275 points. Your [SO flair](http://stackoverflow.com/users/flair/54964.png) shows 9K, your [network flair](http://stackexchange.com/users/flair/22329.png) 12K.