# Change flair regularly

Tags: support, stack-overflow, flair

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is my flair not updated with my actual reputation score?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69401/why-is-my-flair-not-updated-with-my-actual-reputation-score)

I am using flair of Stack Overflow on my site. But whenever my reputation on Stack Overflow increases or decreases, the flair does not update. How to update the flair of Stack Overflow automatically?

I need it to be change automatically by detecting any change in my SO reputation. (This could be a repeated question, I checked but didn't get any matches. If it is a repeated question, please answer in comments only.)

Comment: Three part comment-only-answer - 1.cache, 2. cache, 3. cache. Your flair (and countless other elements of the site) are heavily cached. Give it some time and it will refresh with the correct values.

Comment: ok I got it. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [flair page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1577396/mr-green/Flair):

> (please note that only sites where you have more than 200 reputation will appear, and **that flair is only updated once every 24-36 hours.**)

So you need to wait for 24-36 hours to see the updated flair.

Comment: ok I understood thank you.