# User flair doesn't show the full profile picture

Tags: bug, flair, profile-picture, combined-flair

[image: Half of the picture on user flair]

I have the following issue for a long time now. Before I was thinking that this issue has something to do with a number of reputation points user has, but then the reputation started growing and the situation didn't change.

Any suggestions on what could be an issue for such behaviour?

UPDATE 1:

Re-uploaded the image and waiting for the User Flair to update the image.

UPDATE 2:

After multiple re-uploading attempts I now have the full picture displaying in my user flair.

[image: Full profile picture is displayed correctly]

Is it possible to mention somewhere down the process of uploading the profile picture that it should be 128x128px in `.png` format? I know that the Imgur should support most of the common image formats, but as the practice shows it doesn't do it quite well.

You can disagree, but I think doing this would decrease the number of similar to mine cases.

Comment: Did you try to save the picture under a different format (png instead of jpg) and upload it again?

Comment: I think re-uploading of your profile picture should trigger regeneration of the flair. I suspect a hick-up between SE and imgur or Gravatar (based on which option you used) to be the root cause of this.

Comment: No bug. Sometimes imgur fails to generate certain thumbnail versions when image is uploaded, it just happens. The fix is to re-upload the image. /cc @rene (see animuson comment in the duck dupe for official stamp.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard re-uploaded the image multiple times both in .jpg and .png formats - issue remained the same

Comment: @alljamin flair is heavily cached for over 24 hours. After re-uploading you have to wait [24-36 hours](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/69403/152859) until the flair will use it as well. That said, in this case I believe you can ask a CM to hard-reset your flair, feel free to drop by in the Tavern chat room and ask for this. (currently Jon Ericson and Shog9 are pingable in there.)

Comment: @ShadowWizard can I keep the question open until the issue remains?

Comment: No point "leaving it  open", it's the same issue, and it won't be globally fixed as it's something on imgur side, and they're way too big to care.

Comment: What is the size of the profile image you upload? If it is large, can you resize it before you upload? And you're not using gavatar, right?

Comment: @rene you're right I don't use gravatar. Profile picture is uploaded in 128x128px dimensions.

Comment: @alljamin Ok, I expect to resolve it self in 24 hours then. I don't think the flair batch script runs more frequent then that.